# Implementation of bidi from x/text/unicode/bidi?

Tags: go, unicode, bidi

I try to use the Unicode bidi algorithm from [unicode.org/reports/tr9/](https://unicode.org/reports/tr9/). There is an implementation in Go at [golang.org/x/text/unicode/bidi](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/text/unicode/bidi). This implementation has a limited API, but apparently has completely implemented all rules of the algorithm (see for example https://github.com/golang/text/blob/v0.3.3/unicode/bidi/core.go).

The goal is to have a text split into segments with information about each segment if it is 'left to right' or 'right to left'. The aforementioned algorithm does exactly this, but is not exposed via an API (no public exported functions or structs).

**Question**: how deal with the situation that the implementation is not publicly available? I assume I should use the relevant Go source files directly in my implementation? (I will of course pay attention to the source license).

Comment: "the best way to use the implementation" is very subjective and depends a lot on whether you can use the implementation via the "limited API" or not. What _exactly_ are you trying to do? Can you give a real example?

Comment: @Volker I'll edit my question, thanks for the feedback

Comment: As the API of bidi is not jet fixed the best thing probably would be to contribute this type of API to  package bidi.